# How to enable auto preview mp3's on mouse over on Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, mp3, previews

How to enable auto preview mp3's on mouse over on Ubuntu 12.10. This feature was available in 11.04 but its not present in 12.10. So how to enable it on Ubuntu 12.10.